# Rapidly preview files

Tags: buffers, cycling, previewing

Similar to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/275/dired-quick-view-key-to-preview-the-file-at-point), I'd like a tool/minor mode to quickly preview my files by merely having the cursor positioned over them (e.g. the currently selected file is displayed in the active buffer window). I don't care about depressing events and I don't want an overlay. If it's selected, I want it displayed in the active window. Pressing enter and switching to the buffer is too slow to skim through a bunch of raw data files. How could I do this?

Comment: For those users who use OSX, there is a native application called `qlmanage` that can be used to display the file contents or pdf or image.  Another forum participant has written a function to delete subsequent processes when viewing multiple items (one after another) with said application.  Here is the link to the relevant thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023458/how-to-delete-process-with-similar-name-one-at-a-time-from-newest-to-oldest  I currently have it set up so that I can use the arrow key up or down in a file manager mode and `qlmanage` displays the file contents at point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19907939/729907) is the same as yours.  And the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933337/729907) by the OP is a good one.  There are other good answers there, as well.

Similarly, [this question](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-10/msg00304.html) to help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org is essentially the same also.

My own answer to both questions is to use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) and to define this command:

```
    (defun my-find-file ()
      "Like `icicle-find-file', but alt action views file temporarily.
    Alternate action keys such as `C-S-down' visit the candidate file in
    `view-mode' and kill the buffer of the last such viewed candidate."
      (interactive)
      (let ((icicle-candidate-alt-action-fn
             (lambda (file)
               (when (and my-last-viewed
                          (get-file-buffer my-last-viewed))
                 (kill-buffer (get-file-buffer my-last-viewed)))
               (setq my-last-viewed  (abbreviate-file-name file))
               (view-file file)
               (select-frame-set-input-focus
                  (window-frame (active-minibuffer-window))))))
        (icicle-find-file-of-content)))

    (defvar my-last-viewed nil
      "Last file viewed by alternate action of `my-find-file'.")
```

Then you can:

1. Use `M-x my-find-file` (or bind it to a key - e.g., `C-x C-f`).
2. Optionally type part of a file name, to limit the matching names.
3. Optionally use `down` or `up` to cycle among file names.
4. Use `C-S-down` to visit the next file in order.
5. Repeat #4 to see other files in order.
6. Repeat #2 or #3 to see other sets of files.
7. End with `RET` to choose a file to visit or `C-g` to cancel.

See the linked posts for more info.

Comment: I know its your right to choose your development model. As a user I would like it be on github or in some git repository rather than emacswiki. You don't need to reply to me, just writing here to let you know what I feel. Thanks by the way, for your long continuing efforts in helping emacs users.

Comment: @kindahero: FWIW, all of my libraries are also on [MELPA](www.melpa.org).

Answer (score 11):

I discovered this functionality is already built-in to [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). To use it, use the up and down arrows and press C-up/C-down.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.  There is always something else simple yet amazing to learn about Helm!

Comment: I remember that this used to work at one point, but I tried it recently and got the error message `"Helm-follow-mode allowed only on images, disabling"`.  I tried removing the bit that checks that, and helm-follow-mode appears to still work with regular files, though it's a bit slow to open each file.  Does anyone know why they changed this behavior?