# Select images in auctex with preview

Tags: latex, auctex, icicles

If I insert an image into a latex file (via `\includegraphics`) auctex lets me select the file and inserts the filename.

However using this dialogue, I can only choose the filename and cannot see previews of images as in file chooser dialogues of usual GUI programs.

How can I get this in emacs too? I.e. have image thumbnail previews when selecting an image for my tex file.

**Edit** I just discovered [`icicles`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) mode which generates thumbnails for `find-file`. However it doesn't seem to work with auctex and completion in `\includegraphics` out of the box.

Comment: If you use [`helm`](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) and set `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` to `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-relative` you'll have previews.  Let me know if this satisfies you and I'll write an answer.

Comment: I don't know how to set it up so I didn't try it, but it sounds as it would satisfiy my needs (if it is not too slow and if the thumbnails are not too small)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` to `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-relative`, autocompletion with [`helm`](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) provides this feature:

[image]

---

### Setting up AUCTeX

You can either customize `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>) and select the `relative` option or add the following to your init file:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file 'LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-relative)
```

---

### Installing and setting up `helm`

You can install `helm` from Melpa repository, [here](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started) are the instructions on how to add it.  When you're done, issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-packages` <kbd>RET</kbd>, go to the `helm` entry and hit <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>.

Now you need to setup `helm`.  [Here](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) is a good starting tutorial.  You can choose between a minimal configuration:

```lisp
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
```

and an extended configuration:

```lisp
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)

;; The default "C-x c" is quite close to "C-x C-c", which quits Emacs.
;; Changed to "C-c h". Note: We must set "C-c h" globally, because we
;; cannot change `helm-command-prefix-key' once `helm-config' is loaded.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'helm-command-prefix)
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x c"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x) ; This was not present in the suggested extended config

(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; rebind tab to run persistent action
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; make TAB works in terminal
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z")  'helm-select-action) ; list actions using C-z

(when (executable-find "curl")
  (setq helm-google-suggest-use-curl-p t))

(setq helm-split-window-in-side-p           t ; open helm buffer inside current window, not occupy whole other window
      helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source     t ; move to end or beginning of source when reaching top or bottom of source.
      helm-ff-search-library-in-sexp        t ; search for library in `require' and `declare-function' sexp.
      helm-scroll-amount                    8 ; scroll 8 lines other window using M-<next>/M-<prior>
      helm-ff-file-name-history-use-recentf t)

(helm-mode 1)
```

Please, be aware of the [differences between Emacs default completion and `helm`'s one](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#emacscompletionvshelm).

---

### Start using the new feature

Restart Emacs and you'll be ready.  In an LaTeX buffer, issue <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> `includegraphics` <kbd>RET</kbd> (note you can exploit `helm` autocompletion) and select the picture you want to include.  In order to see the preview, as shown at the beginning, press twice the keybinding associated to `helm-execute-persistent-action` (<kbd>C-z</kbd> by default, or <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the above extended configuration) or move up and down in the file list with <kbd>C-up</kbd> and <kbd>C-down</kbd> (see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2463/620)).

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! The only annoying thing is that you have to press tab twice (and afterwards another shortcut to go back). Ideally the previews should show up just when the point is over the corresponding filename in the file list (so that you can just navigate up and down the file list and instantly see the corresponding previews without pressing any additional keys)

Comment: I think you should ask this a feature request to helm project, but I'm not sure it'll be implemented.

Comment: It seems be helm `helm-follow` mode what is needed. Just press `C-c C-f` when beeing in `helm-find-file` menu, then you can browse through your files with preview. However can I activate helm follow mode as default when entering the helm find file menu? I.E. that I don't need to press `C-c C-f`?

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask this as a new question `;-)`