# Make \includegraphics and TEXINPUTS setting for images work together

Tags: helm, auctex

In my `.profile`-file I have a setting like:

```
export TEXINPUTS=$TEXINPUTS:/home/myuser/projects/images//
```

- If I try to include an image by using `(TeX-insert-macro "includegraphics")`, auctex is in the directory where my current latex file is by default. However I want to be it by default in the directory `/home/myuser/projects/images/`.
- If I include then an image from this dir it gives includes the whole path. But this isn't desired since I have set the `TEXINPUTS` variable. So how can I change this such that it only inserts the filename and not the whole (relative) path?

**Edit**
As suggested by @giordano, setting `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` to `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-TeX` should make it work. However in this case the solution in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14011/2323 doesn't work anymore. However I want both.

**Edit 2**
Maybe one could create a custom helm source for inserting images, which is called when I want to insert an image via auctex (don't see how to bind this). Here is what I tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
(defun helm-image-select ()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources
      (helm-build-async-source "helm-image-select"
        :candidates-process
        (lambda ()
          (start-process "find-images" nil "find" "/home/myuser/projects/images/" "-iname" helm-pattern)) ;; doesn't seem to work, in particular no fuzzy search... should also take all path's from TEXINPUTS as base.
    :action '(("insert-image" . insert-image-action)
          )
    ))
  )

(defun insert-image-action (candidate)
(insert (format "%s" (helm-get-selection))) ;; should return only the filename without the path
)
```

As said above, I also don't know how to connect this to auctex (maybe alternatively, this could be executed if I expand a snipped for includegraphics).

Another problem with the approach above shows up in the case I don't want to add a pictures from a path known by `$TEXINPUTS`. In particular in this case the path has to be insert such that latex can find the image.

Comment: Which is the value of `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file` for you?  If it's `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-relative` the path will be always inserted as relative, otherwise if it's `LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-TeX` it should respect `TEXINPUTS` value (and if it doesn't work automatically add your directory to `TeX-macro-private` variable).

Comment: That would solve the problem, indeed, but it would break your solution to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14011/2323. Any idea?