# How to define a keybinding with a key-down/up (Alt-Tab-like) behaviour

Tags: key-bindings

The usual behavior of `Alt-Tab` in window managers is that as long as `Alt` is pressed, the user can `Tab` or `Shift-Tab` through the list of windows, and then when `Alt` is released the currently selected window is made active.

Can this be replicated with Emacs? AFAIK, keybindings are activated on `key-down`, and there is no way to say: enter a mode where additional  switch through a list and exit (and activate) when `Alt` is released. (Replace `<alt>` and `<tab>` with a modifier + key of choice, I understand that `Alt-Tab` may be fully under the WM's control.)

Comment: You could achieve a very similar behavior with a transient map.  It would not deactivate on key release, but it would deactivate as soon as you pressed any key besides those specified in your transient map.

Comment: Though the question is not a duplIcate, it does have an answer [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/296/50)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been [discussed before](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/275/93), you cannot bind commands to key-up events.  One alternative that comes to mind to achieve similar workflow is to use a transient map like this:

```
(defvar my-cycling-var 0 "Some variable that I am interested in modifying")

(defvar my-transient-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map (kbd "<tab>") 'my-forward-command)
     (define-key map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'my-forward-command)
     (define-key map (kbd "<S-tab>") 'my-backward-command)
     (define-key map (kbd "<C-S-tab>") 'my-backward-command)
     map)
  "A key map used for a demonstration of transient maps")

(defun my-cycling-command ()
"Starts the cycling command and sets the transient key map"
  (interactive)
  (my-forward-command)
  (set-transient-map my-transient-map 'my-keep-keymap))

(defun my-keep-keymap ()
  "This function is called each time a key is pressed while the
transient map is active. If this function returns non-nil, the
keymap will stay active."
  (let* ((key (this-command-keys))
         (binding (lookup-key my-transient-map key)))
    (unless binding
      (my-end-repeatable-command))
    binding))

(defun my-forward-command ()
  "Increment my-cycling-var by one"
  (interactive)
  (setq my-cycling-var (+ 1 my-cycling-var))
  (message "my-cycling-var is %d" my-cycling-var))

(defun my-backward-command ()
  "Decrement my-cycling-var by one"
  (interactive)
  (setq my-cycling-var (+ -1 my-cycling-var))
  (message "my-cycling-var is %d" my-cycling-var))

(defun my-end-repeatable-command ()
  "Take any necessary action after cycling"
  (message "my-cycling-var was set to %d" my-cycling-var))

;; Bind my-repeatable-command to Ctrl+TAB
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'my-cycling-command)
```

This binds `my-cycling-command` to `C-TAB`. Subsequent presses of `TAB` and `S-TAB` or `C-TAB` and `C-S-TAB` will have a cycling effect.  As soon as you press any key that is not `TAB`, `S-TAB`, or `RET`, the overlay map disappears and you resume normal editing.

**Important Note:**  Prior to Emacs 24.4, `set-transient-map` was named `set-temporary-overlay-map`.  To be compatible with earlier versions, you will have to use that function name instead.

Comment: This is close enough, thank you. For the remaining piece, could I have an idle function that's active during the transient map and checks active modifiers? For instance, OS X has `[NSEvent modifierFlags]` method, I wonder if there is anything similar available in elisp.

Comment: I don't think you have access to the raw modifiers from elisp. If you are really set on using a key-up behavior you could check out @JordonBiondo's hack here:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/296/93